Are processes derived from deterministic and square-integrable functions martingales?
Problem

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a deterministic and square-integrable function, i.e. $\int_0^\infty f(t)^2\mathrm{d}t < \infty$, and define the process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ by $X_t := f(t)$.

Is the process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ a (local) martingale?
Is the stochastic integral process $\left(\int_{0}^{t}X_s\mathrm{d}B_s\right)_{t\geq 0}$ a (local) martingale?
Is the stochastic exponential process $\left(e^{\int_{0}^{t}X_s\mathrm{d}B_s-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}X_s^2\mathrm{d}s}\right)_{t\geq 0}$ a (local) martingale?


The easy part
Note that if $f(t)=0$, then all three processes in question are martingales and therefore local martingales as well. It remains to be examined if this is true in general.



From the martingale condition for $X$ follows $f(t)=\mathbb{E}\left[X_t\vert\mathcal{F}_s\right] = X_s = f(s)$ for all $s<t$. Therefore, $f$ must be constant, but the only square-integrable constant function is $f(t)=0$. It follows that $X$ is a martingale if and only if $f(t)=0$.
Now, assume that there exists an increasing sequence of stopping times $(\tau_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $\tau_n\nearrow\infty$ (a.s.) such that $X^{\tau_n}=(X_{t\wedge\tau_n})_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. From the martingale condition for $X^{\tau_n}$ follows $f(t\land \tau_n)=\mathbb{E}\left[X^{\tau_n}_t\vert\mathcal{F}_s\right] = X^{\tau_n}_s = f(s\land \tau_n)$. This only holds if $\tau_n = 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (which is not possible since $\tau_n\nearrow\infty$ (a.s.)) or if $f$ is constant. Just like before, it follows that $X$ is a local martingale if and only if $f(t)=0$



Ideas for (2.) and (3.)

$X$ is deterministic and therefore adapted. If I could show that $X$ is (a.s.) continuous, then it would be a progressive square-integrable process and it would follow that $\left(\int_{0}^{t}X_s\mathrm{d}B_s\right)_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale and therefore a local martingale as well. However, $X$ being (a.s.) continuous does not follow from $X$ being square-integrable, so I need to show either that $X$ is (a.s.) continuous (which I am not sure about) or directly show that $X$ is progressive (which sounds more likely to me). I don't know how to do either.

Again, I need that $X$ is a progressive square-integrable process. Then I could finish things off by noting that Novikov's criterion follows from $f$ being square-integrable:
$$\int_0^\infty f(t)^2\mathrm{d}t < \infty\ \Rightarrow\ \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)^2\mathrm{d}t}\right] < \infty$$ Novikov's criterion would yield that $\left(e^{\int_{0}^{t}X_s\mathrm{d}B_s-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}X_s^2\mathrm{d}s}\right)_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale and therefore local martingale as well.


Questions

Is all my reasoning so far correct?
How can I show that $X$ is progressive?


I am a bit rusty on these topics, so I am a bit hesistant to firmly answer your 2 questions.   Just wanted to add that in (2.) you do not need an (a.s.) continuous process $X$. Square integrability + measurability is enough, and you in fact get that $\int_0^{t} X_{s}dB_{s} \sim N(0, \int_{0}^{t}X_{s}^{2}ds)$. The details elude me a bit here, so hopefully someone else is able to fill in the gaps
